# What is the difference — honor, confer, decorate —?

Tags: differences, nuance

I’m a Japanese college student, and in English class, I saw a sentence saying,

> The prime minister was formally invested with the title by Emperor.

When I looked up words which mean "to give a title" in the dictionary, I found that “confer”, “decorate” and “honor” can also be used in the same sense.

These words translate the same when translated into Japanese, but what nuances does each word have in English?

Answer (score 1):

These words are used in connection with the same idea, but not exactly in the same sense.

The monarch doesn't confer a person, they **confer** a title or honour **on** them.

When the monarch **decorates** someone, they give them a medal (like decorating a Christmas tree by hanging things on it).

**Honour** as a noun can mean 'a title or award given to someone'; as a verb it can mean 'give a title or award to someone'.

Answer (score 0):

This is country specific, but the usual word seems to be "appoint".

For Japan, Article 6 of the Constitution says (in the official English translation) "The Emperor shall appoint the Prime Minister as designated by the Diet."

In the UK without a constitution, it is a little messier.  The King "invited" Rishi Sunak to form a government on 28 November 2022, but only "appointed" him as one of [seven Lords Commissioners of His Majesty’s Treasury](https://www.thegazette.co.uk/notice/4225960), and by putting him first on the list had the effect of making him Prime Minister.

Answer (score -1):

confer - to award someone, often used in the context of education and the completion of a course. To confer someone with a degree for example.

decorate - to award someone, used in the context of military. A decorated soldier for example.

honor - to mark a milestone. Honouring someone for 50 years service, for reaching 100th birthday etc. Used in the British honour system.

Invest - to induct someone to a society that indicates prestige, power and decision making.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The British honours system isn't for marking milestones; it's for thanking people for service to the community, not necessarily for a particular period of time.